# Is it on topic to ask for the name of a plant?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is it on topic to ask for the name of a plant? I asked for the name of my aloes, and the response was poor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is on topic, but it is very difficult to give a specific variety name. There's a strong chance your aloes don't have one - aloes hybridize easily. It would be like me trying to find a name for my prickly pears - I have a general idea but at the end of the day I use my own generic names to distinguish most of the types I have.